# What is "on-topic"?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

The current [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page is lacking.

> Magento Stack Exchange is for users of and developers working with the Magento e-Commerce platform.

There have been several discussions about what is on-topic on meta, but no action has been taken on the page. I don't know how many people actually read before posting :/, but for the people who do wish to join the community and contribute to [magento.stackexchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com) it may be helpful to point to what is and isn't an acceptable question.

- [Questions about extensions](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/questions-about-extensions)
- [What to do with questions & answers regarding free extensions?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134/what-to-do-with-questions-answers-regarding-free-extensions)
- ["What did you do before posting"](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103/what-did-you-do-before-posting)

Of course writing our own would be best, but at the very least, we could copy a bit from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com):

> the best [Magento] questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers...
>
> - a specific [Magento] programming problem
> - <s>a software algorithm</s>
> - [Magento extensions or] tools [which are free or] commonly used <s>by programmers</s>
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to [Magento] software development
>
> ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

The **extensions or tools** bullet will confuse people, so it may need additional verbiage like "- This is not a support forum for Module XYZ. Do not assume that anybody but you owns/uses your module, so do you research in debugging the module."