# Closing questions

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've been working lately on cleaning up the old and unanswered questions.
(My hidden agenda is to get the answered percentage as high as possible but this is not why I ask this).

So I've been [browsing this section](https://magento.stackexchange.com/unanswered) and tried to answer some of the questions and close others.
I admit that maybe I was overdoing it and voted to close some of the questions that shouldn't be closed. But I guess that's why you need more than one vote to close a question.
But I'm almost sure that most of the questions should be closed.
I've [read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583) to get an idea of what should be closed and what shouldn't, but this is kind of vague and it depends on each SO website in particular. So I went on and took a [look here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

My conclusion... we should define a better scope of this website.
There are a lot of questions still open that are not going to help future readers or questions requesting for very custom code that apply to one case only.
Here are some of them:

- [Saving a review requires a website ID?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/15371/146)
- [Page content in CMS doesn't reflect live page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/9880/146)
- [Which Magento modules allow to set tiered pricing depending on category?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/13717/146)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/13195/146

And I can go on if needed.

**To sum this up...I have 2 questions:**

1. *How can we define a little clearer the questions that can be asked here?*
2. *How can we make the voters more responsible for their actions? I know that clicking "Leave open" is easier than to read the question and maybe provide a reason for closing but let's try to keep a clean website.*

**[EDIT]**
This turned you to be a *"here is why I didn't closed the question"* list.
I wasn't expecting that. I don't care about the reasons you don't close questions. I'm sure (most of them) are legit reasons.
I wanted to focus more on how we can make the closing process and the on topic questions a little more clear...if that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side note, [this is related](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/what-is-on-topic).

As a moderator I try to be *very* careful when closing questions or deleting answers. I always stop to consider that it may not seem relevant to me, but it might be relevant to someone else. A good example are the non-code questions, which I believe we have decided to allow as a community. That was part of the logic for starting this site in the first place.

Above all, the Stack Exchange ethos dictates that we correct rather than censor content; in other words, the goal should be to help people ask better questions or write better answers rather than make their content (or them) go away.

I apologize for the occasional inconsistency in which close/delete requests are handled, and I do wish that we had some clear reference in place which can always be cited. When I err though I will always err on the side of leaving things open.

As a side note, I sure wish there were something besides chat to have the extended discussions in comments. Sometimes it's really necessary and historically valuable.

Answer (score 1):

To speak for me, who did vote against closing for at least one of your examples:

I voted against the closing of [Which Magento modules allow to set tiered pricing depending on category?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13717/which-magento-modules-allow-to-set-tiered-pricing-depending-on-category) as I could see a valid but bad formulated Question. So instead I made the Question more clear with an edit. I think we are not only responsible to clean up, we are also responsible for improve possible valuable questions.

I know my answer on this question is far away from being good (thats another issue), but I see the question as valid and think it could help other people. Maybe it still needs some more content/focus.

Other questions,
especially the a few day old questions get partially skipped from me, dont know how this affects the result